# schema.yml using sfDoctrineGuardPlugin

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, sfdoctrineguard

I'm building a schema.yml and I'm trying to add foreign key constraints to the table sf_guard_user.

But, when I do doctrine:insert-sql (edit: doctrine:build --all), the links between my tables and sf_guard_user are not there ! Am I missing something ?

I'm using mysql (**InnoDB**) and Symfony 1.4

Here's a sample of my schema.yml :

```
Author:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: ec_author
  actAs:
    Sluggable:
      fields: [name]
      unique: true
      canUpdate: false
  columns:
    sf_guard_user_id:
      type: integer
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    name:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    contents:
      type: string()
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
      User:
        class: sfGuardUser
        foreignType: one
        local: sf_guard_user_id
        foreign: id
```

There are no links to sfGuardUser, even though they are described in schema.yml :
[image]
[image]

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: Manu, does the relation exist in the BaseAuthor class? Is there a call to $this->hasOne('sfGuardUser...'?

Comment: No, no this->hasone in BaseAuthor

Comment: Do I need to modify the plugin's schema or is what I am doing supposed to work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one works:

```
Author:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: ec_author
  actAs:
    Sluggable:
      fields: [name]
      unique: true
      canUpdate: false
  columns:
    sf_guard_user_id:
      type: integer
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    name:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    contents:
      type: string()
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
      User:
        class: sfGuardUser
        foreignType: one
        local: sf_guard_user_id
        foreign: id
        foreignAlias: author
```

sf_guard_user_id is a foreign key, then it can't be a primary key. so I changed 
`primary: true` to `primary: false`.

Comment: By the way, there will be a primary key named id in your table ec_author. It is generated automatically(if you didn't declare a primary key explicitly).

Answer (score 1):

You should be rebuilding the models and sql as well. Try running:

```
symfony doctrine:build --all
```

This will clobber all existing data. If you don't want that, you'll have to write a migration.

Comment: +1 insert-sql just inserts the schema.sql file. If you do not regenerate it, it won't work.

Comment: Even with build --all the links aren't there. Am I supposed to change the schema.yml inside the plugin ?

Comment: When you say the links aren't there, where are they missing? Is it missing in SQL (i.e. no FK from sf_guard_user_id to sf_guard_user table)? Does BaseAuthor add a relation from sf_guard_user_id to User?

Comment: In sql yes. Also, I can't create a fixture for sfguarduser with data from the profile table (Authors)

Answer (score 1):

The Class name needs to be the same name as you specified when opening the corresponding table in your schema file.

So, for example, you are using:

```
relations:
    User:
      class: sfGuardUser
      foreignType: one
```

The class name here must match the declaration of the sfGuardUser table.  Just make sure they are the same.  Sometimes, it can be declared as sf_guard_user.

If that is fine, you can try adding a few more definitions to your Relations entry:

```
relations:
    User:
      class: sfGuardUser
      foreignType: one
      local: sf_guard_user_id
      foreign: sf_guard_user_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've added your suggestions but the link still isn't there :(

Comment: Are you able to populate the tables?  Does it cause a FK error when you try to add a FK that does not exist?